# How to capture windows to a set of split Windows image (.swm) files by using DISM?

Tags: windows, dism

Reference to MSDN:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14?view=windows-11

I can capture my windows volume to a wim file image, eg:

```
Dism /Capture-Image /ImageFile:Drive-C.wim /CaptureDir:C:\ /Name:Drive-C
```

But the `Drive-C.wim` is too big to store in my FAT32 USB storage(over 4GB).

Is there a solution to capture my windows volume to a set of split Windows image (.swm) files by using DISM command?

Answer (score 0):

have u tried /FileSize:XXX just like the /Split-Image command ?

```
Dism /Capture-Image /ImageFile:Drive-C.wim /CaptureDir:C:\ /Name:Drive-C /FileSize:2048
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Error: 87
The /filesize option is not recognized in this context.